# Excluding files in packaging Gradle

Tags: gradle, packaging

I have a requirement in which I have to exclude certain files from META-INF and OSG-INF during packaging in gradle. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html) You can find detailed DSL for `war` packaging. Search for `exclude`.

Comment: I have excluded required files from the jar, thanks....Adding to this, I have a requirement that each jar of subproject which are dependent on each other need to have a file excluded during packaging after all the test cases have run successfully...so the final jar of each subproject received should not be having that spring.xml but that spring.xml should be present when the tests run...Any help on this?

Comment: No idea what the problem is :/ Set up a sample project and share it via GH to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I have got the solution for this...Included a folder of resources under test folder and included spring.xml over there..now its not picking the source code...Thanks..:)